# C++ equivilent of SHA1Managed.ComputeHash

Tags: c#, c++, sha

I have this C# code:

```
SHA1Managed hash = new SHA1Managed();
byte[] computedHash = hash.ComputeHash(_decryptedBytes);
```

I need to convert this code to C++, which functions should I be using?

Particularly the equivilent of SHA1Managed.ComputeHash

Comment: SHA1 is a standardized hash algorithm, and there are tons of C++ implementations.  Have you done any research before posting?

Comment: Yep. I'm not really sure on C++. I think perhaps it is the CryptHashData function but I'm not really sure. It is quite new to me.

Comment: if you're on windows you're probably looking for [Cryptography Next Generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

boost has an SHA1 implementation http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/boost/classboost_1_1uuids_1_1detail_1_1sha1.html